# How to make launch files?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been reading some examples of ROS programs, and one of my questions so far is **how can I create the launch file** I need for the purpose of my program?, what is the correct scheme?, where can I find some sort of a list of commands I need in order to create a launch file? Is there any documentation about it?

Thanks (:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32320/how-to-make-launch-files?/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [roslaunch wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML) should have everything you need.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khalilrkhouri@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/26288/khalilrkhouri@gmail.com/) on 2016-03-15**:
Use getit to creat a new file.
An example is in the comments of http://answers.ros.org/question/62743/how-to-create-a-launch-file/